# Update multiple records with multiple conditions

Tags: sql

I am trying to update several records in my SQL table.  My data looks like this

```
Name
Record1_Name
Record1_Name_something
Record2_Data_Name
Record2_Name_something
```

The results need to be

```
Name
Record1
Record2
Record2_Data
```

Here is the code that I have so far

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Column1 = 
CASE 1
WHEN '%Record1%' THEN 'Record1'
WHEN '%Record2%' AND '%Data%' THEN 'Record2_Data'
WHEN '%Record2%' AND NOT '%Data%' Then 'Record2'
```

The first when works with no issue.  The second I add the AND, though, it fails.  I know the syntax is off on the last one but that is something I will need to try as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for something this:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Column1 = CASE 
                 WHEN Column1 LIKE '%Record1%' THEN 'Record1'
                 WHEN Column1 LIKE '%Record2%' AND Column1 LIKE '%Data%' THEN 'Record2_Data'
                 WHEN Column1 LIKE '%Record2%' AND Column1 NOT LIKE '%Data%' Then 'Record2'
                 ELSE 'Record3'
              END
```

**Note:** You need to specify a value that is returned in case none of the case boolean expressions is satisfied. Otherwise, `CASE` returns `NULL`.

Comment: Crap yeah my syntax was off.  I had been trying so many times, I lost my LIKE statement.  Thank you.

Comment: Actually I just tried the one statement and I get the error "Cannot insert the value NULL into column column1; column does not allow nulls.  Can't figure out why it is trying to add null

Comment: @maltman That's because none of the `WHEN` predicates are satisfied. You have to specify an alternative using `ELSE`.

Comment: That is weird that they wouldn't be satisfied.  The SELECT works fine. SELECT * FROM Table1 Where column1 LIKE '%Record2%' AND column1 LIKE '%Data%'

Comment: @maltman What does *work fine* mean? Does the above query return *all* table records?

Comment: Yeah the SELECT does.  I have 6 records and they all return.  The update fails

Comment: And this works.  UPDATE Table1 SET Column1 = 'Record2' WHERE Column1 LIKE '%Record2%' AND Column1 LIKE '%Data%'

Comment: @maltman Then the issue must be the column name. I am using `Name` in my answer because I thought that's the column name used by the `UPDATE` operation.

Comment: Yeah the column is Name.  So it would be UPDATE Table1 SET Name = CASE WHEN Name LIKE 'something' THEN 'something'

Comment: ok so now it works.  Ran the same statement.  Let me reboot my computer

Comment: Typo in my Else.  I fixed it in one of the queries but not the one I was testing with.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think your case syntax is off -- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154721/difference-in-results-between-case-syntax

this should work

```
 `UPDATE Table1

SET Column1 = CASE WHEN NAME LIKE '%Record1%' THEN 'Record1' WHEN NAME LIKE '%Record2%'
            AND NAME LIKE '%Data%' THEN 'Record2_Data' WHEN NAME LIKE '%Record2%'
            AND NAME NOT LIKE '%Data%' THEN 'Record2' end`
```

Comment: Yeah I lost my LIKE somewhere along the lines of testing.  Thank you